# DEFAULT EMPTY_CLOB()

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  ID    NUMBER,
  COL1  NCLOB                                   DEFAULT 'EMPTY_CLOB()',
  COL2  NCLOB                                   DEFAULT EMPTY_CLOB(),
  COL3  NCLOB                                   DEFAULT (EMPTY_CLOB())
);
```

What is the diferrence between DEFAULT 'EMPTY_CLOB()' and DEFAULT EMPTY_CLOB() and DEFAULT (EMPTY_CLOB()). All empty_clob() output same or are they different?

```
INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES(1);

SELECT ID, LENGTH(COL1), LENGTH(COL2), LENGTH(COL3) FROM TEST;
```

output:

```
1   12  0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'EMPTY_CLOB()'` is a string constant.

`EMPTY_CLOB()` and `(EMPTY_CLOB())` are the same.

They return a LOB locator pointing to an initialized but empty LOB.

[LOB Column States](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/working-with-LOBs.html#GUID-7016B1B2-A666-4567-8083-16D89CB2F52A)

> A cell in a LOB Column can be in one of the following states:
>
> **NULL**
>
> The table cell is created, but the cell holds no locator or value.
>
> **Empty**
>
> A LOB instance with a locator exists in the cell, but it has no value.
>   The length of the LOB is zero.
>
> **Populated**
>
> A LOB instance with a locator and a value exists in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

`DEFAULT 'EMPTY_CLOB()'` is useless. It inserts the **text** `'EMPTY_CLOB()'` to your table. String "EMPTY_CLOB()" has 12 characters as you see.

`EMPTY_CLOB()` and `(EMPTY_CLOB())` should be the same, i.e. an empty CLOB.